Instantiating SqliteConnection throws exception when targetting Windows OS
I'm having an issue using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite in a .NET console app that targets Windows OS.

.NET 8
Console App
Targeting Windows OS v10.0.19041.0
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 8.06

The following code
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

using var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source = test.db");

throws exception
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80073D54
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  Source=WinRT.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|39_0(Int32 hr)
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Windows.Storage.IApplicationDataStaticsMethods.get_Current(IObjectReference _obj)
   at Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_Current()
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

I can debug past the exception with no apparent issue, even able to read and write from the database. Changing the target OS to 'none' causes the exception to go away.
Edit: see below for the full code to reproduce the issue (only 2 files)
ConsoleApp1.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.0.22621.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="8.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Program.cs
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

using var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source = test.db");

Changing ConsoleApp1.csproj so that target OS is 'none' works fine
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="8.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Your code's calling WinRT's ApplicationData.Current and fails, it's probably a packaging issue but the C# you show is insufficient to say more. You should expose all your projects files (csproj, etc.)

Fair enough - I've added the full code that reproduces the issue

I don't reproduce any problem with the code you show.

Perhaps there is a problem on my machine then. Thanks for taking a look!

I'm encountering the same problem. Did you find a solution or problem on your machine?

Yes, debug settings have to be changed so it doesn't break unnecessarily. If I remember correctly you have to disable "break when exceptions cross appdomain or managed/native boundaries"

I had "break when exceptions cross appdomain or managed/native boundaries" already disabled and was having the issue. Your comment pointed me in a helpful direction though; enabling "Enable Just My Code" in Options > Debugging > General suppresses the error. Not ideal, but at least the app is usable.
